# Is this the cleanest way to code the sorting of a table in Excel?

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

Here's the code I've written to sort a table based on two columns then deselect the table once that's done. Is there a cleaner way to code this?

```
Sub SortTable()

    ' Sorts table

    Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table").Sort.SortFields. _
        Clear
    Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("Table[Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("Table[Info]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' Clears table selection

    With Worksheets("Data")
        .Activate
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Code Review is done at [CodeReview.se]

Comment: Oh! I didn't know about that. I'll remember for next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the position of the columns to sort, then this method seems to clean things up.

```
With Sheets("data").ListObjects("Table")
    .Range.Sort Key1:=.ListColumns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Key2:=.ListColumns(4), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    .Parent.Range("A1").Select
End With
```

For the above, the Date list column is 2 and Info is 4. If you don't know the column ordinals then you need to reference the columns from the parent worksheet.

```
With Sheets("data").ListObjects("Table")
    .Range.Sort Key1:=.Parent.Range("Table[Date]"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Key2:=.Parent.Range("Table[Info]"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    .Parent.Range("A1").Select
End With
```

Comment: Is there no need to clear the sort fields if I'm going to be including this at the end of a macro that will be run multiple times?

Comment: No there is no need to clear previous sort keys. You are not adding sort keys to a collection of sort fields; you are specifying Key1 and Key2. Note that this only works to a maximum of 3 sort keys. If you need more than 3, sort once on the secondary set of key(s) then sort again on the primary 3 keys.

Comment: However, you might want to add `.Sort.SortFields.Clear` as the first line of code within the With ... End With to remove the sort icon from the table's header. The icon is irrelevant to the actual final sort order and may be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it tidier by moving your With

```
Sub SortTable()

    ' Sorts table
     With Worksheets("Data").ListObjects("Table").Sort

        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Range("Table[Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
                xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("Table[Info]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
                xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
         End With
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ' Clears table selection

    With Worksheets("Data")
        .Activate
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With

End Sub
```