# Excel Active Sheet | Active Table | Sort

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, vba

I am looking to sort An Active Worksheet/Active table. I will be using an excel file that will be growing daily and each day will have a new sheet/table. I am looking to have everything automatically setup for a different employee to do the work.

I found using **ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)** will choose the active table, but sorting is causing issues.

If i use the following format it would be a one time sort, that in the end would be useless for my employee.

```
Sub Test()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Client Name]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
        :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
 Sub Test()

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)[[#All],[Client Name]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
        :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

All codes go back to the label of the table. How can I modify this to just use what is active?

Comment: You may be interested in [Is this the cleanest way to code the sorting of a table in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887998/is-this-the-cleanest-way-to-code-the-sorting-of-a-table-in-excel/48888318#48888318)

Comment: ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1) will **not** choose the active table if there are more than one table and anything other than the first table is being edited.

Comment: There will only be one table per sheet. I know it will choose the first table of the active sheet. Sorry, I did not phrase that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you the following code will do what you expect, the main different is in the Key, I used the name property of the ListObject to get the correct name in there:

```
 Sub Test()
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name & "[[#All],[Client Name]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
        :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```